# DOCKER for setting up BitBucket

Tags: docker, bitbucket

I want to setup BitBucket on a my server.
BitBucket needs
 Web Server and 
 Postgresql Db server.

So can I setup a docker container with all these installed.
My goal is also to create a single script which can setup the above environment, without the need to give difficult instructions to someone and download binaries individually, setup start-up etc..

Please point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can run both servers with official images:

- *Bitbucket* with the image [`atlassian/bitbucket-server`](https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/bitbucket-server/) and
- *PostgreSQL* with the image [`postgres`](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/postgres/).

Follow the descriptions there. Be aware that you need to use [data-volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/data-volumes) to persist the Bitbucket repositories and the PostgreSQL database files.

To link both together, an easy way would be to use [Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/). Or use

`docker run --link postgres-container-name bitbucket`.